# Measurable, bounded set with positive measure and its subset

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have some problems with the question below, although I think that it's not that difficult to solve.

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable and bounded. Show that for all $x\in\left[0,l_{1}(A)\right]$ there exists measurable subset $A_{x}\subset A$ that satisfies
>    $l_{1}\left(A_{x}\right)=x$.

Because A is bounded there exists such a and b ($a<b$) that $A\subset\left[a,b\right]$.

I tried starting with the function $f\left(x\right)= m\left(\left[a,\,x\right]\cap\,A\right)$

It's increasing and I have to show that it's also continuous which I can't. Then, using property of Darboux, we will have the thesis.

Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: $A\in \mathbb R?$ No. And what is $l_1(A)?$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry for my oversight. It's Lebesgue's measure for 1 dimension.

Comment: If $l_1$ is Lebesgue measure then what is $m$?

Comment: Well, I wanted it to be measure on $\mathbb R$, but I hope there's no problem that it becomes Lebesgue's measure, because the argument is a measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x <y$ Then $|f(x)-f(y)| =m((x,y]\cap A)$  because $[a,y]$ is the disjoint union of $[a,x]$ and $(x,y]$. Hence $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq m((x,y])=y-x$.  hence $f$ is continuous.